# jQuery selector not showing the selected value of checkbox after click on submit button and i am getting error[object Object]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

Hi i have small project in which i have tab 1 i.e FahrzeugeWidget and tab 2 i.e FahrzeugeWidgetEdit. In 1 tab i have list and in second tab i have checkbox list from which i want to select what users want and then then switch to tab1 after submit button and show only values selected from checkbox.I used jQuery selector for same.Every thing is running fine. Only i am not able to get the values selected from checkbox after submit button.There is only small mistake i as doing not able to identify.Here is fiddle:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RCL8N/2/) So i should only get those values selected from checkbox. Here is my code:

dashboard.php

```
if($param['aktion'] == 'save-widget-vehicle')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],''),
        0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','enabled',$page['script'],'',''), 
    );

        $opts = !empty($param['filterOpts']) ? $param['filterOpts'] : array();

      $tmp = array();
      foreach ($opts as $opt) {
            $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
      }
             $query = 
          'SELECT Fahrzeuge.dsnr,name
           FROM Fahrzeuge
           INNER JOIN ohne_fahrzeuge ON Fahrzeuge.dsnr = ohne_fahrzeuge.dsnr
           WHERE Fahrzeuge.name IN ('.implode(",", $tmp).')';

      $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);
      $data = array();
        $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
                        '.CreateMessage().'
                        <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register"> ';
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){       
                        //$news_result = $fahrzeuge['name']; 
                        $html .= '<table id="fahrzeuge"> 
                                        <tr>
                                    <td>                                        
                                            <a href="amo_fahrzeuge.php"> '. $data[] = $row .'</a>                                       
                                </td>                               
                            </tr> ';                                
                              }

                        $html .= '</table>          
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';


                    $return = array(
            'status' => 1,
            'html'  => $html
        );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();

      $param['aktion'] = 'get-widget-vehicle';
}
```

dashboard.js

```
function getFahrzeuge() {   
    var opts = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
     if (this.checked) {
         opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
     }
    }); 
    return opts;
 }


    function saveFahrzeugeWidget(opts){
        if(!opts || !opts.length){
          opts = allFahrzeuge;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts, 'aktion' : 'save-widget-vehicle'},
          success: function(data){
           // $('#fahrzeuge').html(makeTable(records));
             $('#fahrzeuge').html(data.html);
          },
      error: function(data){
                alert('error' + data);
          }
        });
      }


      $('#fahrzeuge .butt-rahmen').live('click', function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'submitId')
            var opts = getFahrzeuge();
            saveFahrzeugeWidget(opts);

           //   $("#regl1").show();
           //   $("#regl1").hide();

 });
      var allFahrzeuge = [];
      $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        allFahrzeuge.push($(this)[0].id)
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your problem but which JQuery version are you using? The JQuery function `.live()` is depricated since version 1.9. You must use `.on()` instead. May you don't get the values because the action isn't triggered by the use of the `live()` function?

Comment: no its not the issue i am working with the older version of jquery but not getting any problem...

Comment: Dp you perhaps have a JSFiddle with some sample code. Can you make one without the PHP part?

Comment: Please check the edited fiddle buit its incomplete without php. I have only problem in jquery i guess: http://jsfiddle.net/RCL8N/2/   So as in fiddle i will only get those value selected from checkbox..

Comment: Like stated: you're using Jquery version *1.10.1*. The event `.live()` is depricated as from version version *1.9.1* and there is not available in version *1.10.1*. You must use `.on()` function instead. Please refactor you code using `.on()` and revise. Also there isn't a submit button in you HTML so I can't test it. Look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQLqZ/1) it's based on version 1.10.1 you use. It will not alert you content. Change the version to 1.8.3 and run it and it will alert you content. The function you use just won't work with the version of JQuery.

Comment: yes i know but its not the problem in my code ...i already working with older version and i am using live func but not getting any problem...and i tried to use .on() but still not getting any answer

Comment: Sorry wihtout any usefull code I can't help. I can conclude that you're using wrong function with wrong JQuery version. I've added a button to your code and used `.on()` instead of `.live()`. I can get track of the checked items, they will alert now: [http://jsfiddle.net/RCL8N/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/RCL8N/3/). You code works if you add a button to the HTML and if you use `.on()` (in JSFiddle).

Comment: i try to get the error now using error function() and i am getting error[object Object]. Do u know any solution for this ?

Comment: can you please check on this i have just posted new post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328210/ajax-calls-getting-errorobject-object?noredirect=1#comment37606889_24328210